# How does ranking adjustment in Wii Sports Boxing work?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-sports

The ranking adjustment system in Wii Sports Boxing confounds me.

My current ranking is in the 800s, and the opponents pitted against me by the game are ranked from 900 to over 1000.

I regularly beat the higher-ranked CPU opponent - sometimes by KO, sometimes not - but most of the time it results in my ranking score slightly decreasing.

This doesn't make sense to me at all! If I beat a higher-ranked opponent, shouldn't my ranking increase?

If not, then how does the ranking work?

Comment: I think it has to do with the strength of the win too.  The faster you beat your opponent, the more your rating goes up.  If you just eke out a win, you're where you should be and your rating doesn't change by a lot.  This is pure speculation, though, which is why it's a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[source:](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Wii_Sports/Boxing#Skill_Points)

> **Skill Points**
>
> The only way of improving your skill
>   level is by playing the game in
>   single-player mode. It doesn't get
>   affected in multiplayer. If you win,
>   your skill level will increase and the
>   computer player will be tougher the
>    next time around. **The more times you get knocked down in a fight, the fewer skill points you will earn. The higher your skill level, the larger this penalty is.**
>   The maximum number of
>   points you can earn for each fight is
>   76. It is possible to win a match yet still lose points.